# jUnit on eclipse Indigo

Tags: java, junit, eclipse-indigo

I installed Eclipse IDE for JavaScript Web Developers, Version: Indigo Service Release 1
Build id: 20110916-0149, in 2011 and use it for java development now but can see no menu about jUnit when I right click on a java class.
Actually jUnit appears nowhere in the menus.

After going around forums, I tried to install JDT, as I understood this is where jUnit is contained. But installation failed because of a conflict with something already installed...

Can you help please ?

FRED

Conflict details :

```
I get : Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Eclipse Java Development Tools 3.7.2.v20120120-1414-7z8gFcuFMP7BW5XTz0jLTnz0l9B1 (org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group 3.7.2.v20120120-1414-7z8gFcuFMP7BW5XTz0jLTnz0l9B1)
  Software currently installed: Shared profile 1.0.0.1325791064663 (SharedProfile_epp.package.javascript 1.0.0.1325791064663)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Java Development Tools Launching Support 3.5.0.v20090527 (org.eclipse.jdt.launching 3.5.0.v20090527)
    Java Development Tools Launching Support 3.6.0.v20110509 (org.eclipse.jdt.launching 3.6.0.v20110509)
    Java Development Tools Launching Support 3.6.1.v20110803_r371 (org.eclipse.jdt.launching 3.6.1.v20110803_r371)
    Java Development Tools Launching Support 3.5.1.v20100108_r352 (org.eclipse.jdt.launching 3.5.1.v20100108_r352)
    Java Development Tools Launching Support 3.6.1.v20111006_r372 (org.eclipse.jdt.launching 3.6.1.v20111006_r372)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Shared profile 1.0.0.1325791064663 (SharedProfile_epp.package.javascript 1.0.0.1325791064663)
    To: org.eclipse.jdt.launching [3.6.1.v20110803_r371]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Java Development Tools 3.7.2.v20120120-1414-7z8gFcuFMP7BW5XTz0jLTnz0l9B1 (org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group 3.7.2.v20120120-1414-7z8gFcuFMP7BW5XTz0jLTnz0l9B1)
    To: org.eclipse.jdt.launching [3.6.1.v20111006_r372]
```

Comment: Can you post what error message you get.?

Comment: please see first message update. Thanks.

Comment: Do you already have JDT installed ?...can u try switching to Java perspective ?

Comment: I am on Java perspective and never installed anything since eclipse main installation

Answer (score 0):

This looks pretty odd. Some background:

The plugin "Java Development Tools Launching Support" doesn't like to have different versions of itself installed in Eclipse. Eclipse 3.7.2 comes with version `3.6.1.v20111006_r372`.

It seems that you still have old versions from 3.5 and 3.6 installed. Did you upgrade from an old version to 3.7?

Problems like that are usually only solvable by installing Eclipse again. Deleting the plugin on the disk won't help because p2 remembers which plugins are installed and doesn't care whether the plugin still exists. You probably also can't delete the plugin because some other plugin will depend on it.

Comment: I did have a previous eclipse installation before Indigo. What version of eclipse is best to install from scratch if I want to use java/Perl/Javascript/HTML ? Thanks

Comment: If you install again, then the latest since it will be the one for which you can get support.

Comment: Which Eclipse version do you recomment to install for my  java/Perl/Javascript/HTML developments ? Thanks

Comment: Install Eclipse e4, J2EE version and then the Perl plugin via the Marketplace.

Comment: Thanks. Will it override completely my current installation ?

Comment: No, you can install it in a new folder and keep the old one. You should **not** install the new version over the old one.